# My Function chain doesn't want to work, why?

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

**GLRectangle.h**

```
#include "XPView.h"

class GLRectangle
{
public:
    int top, left, bottom, right;

public:
    GLRectangle(void);
    ~GLRectangle(void);
    GLRectangle* centerRect(int rectWidth, int rectHeight, int boundWidth=0, int boundHeight=0);
};
```

**GLRectangle.cpp**

```
#include "GLRectangle.h"

GLRectangle::GLRectangle(void)
{
}

GLRectangle::~GLRectangle(void)
{
}

GLRectangle* GLRectangle::centerRect(int rectWidth, int rectHeight, int boundWidth, int boundHeight)
{
    if(boundWidth == 0)
    {
        boundWidth = XPView::getWindowWidth();
    }

    if(boundHeight == 0)
    {
        boundHeight = XPView::getWindowHeight();
    }

    // Set rectangle attributes
    left   = boundWidth / 2 - rectWidth / 2;
    top    = boundHeight / 2 + rectHeight / 2;
    right  = boundWidth / 2 + rectWidth / 2;
    bottom = boundHeight / 2- rectHeight / 2;

    return this;
}
```

and I'm trying to chain a function onto the construction of the object as follows:

```
wndRect = new GLRectangle()->centerRect(400, 160);
```

but getting the following error:

```
error C2143: syntax error:missing ';' before '->'
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [operator precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence) problem.  Try

```
// Add some brackets
wndRect = (new GLRectangle())->centerRect(400, 160);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(wndRect = new GLRectangle())->centerRect(400, 160);
```

but why do this? Why not provide parameters to your constructor so you can say:

```
wndRect = new GLRectangle( 400, 160 );
```

Comment: I think you might have misplaced you first parenthesis

Comment: The constructor will also work, but I want to keep the code self documenting and self explanatory if I can. Maybe I should consider: wndRect = (new GLRectangle(400, 160))->center(); // Mmmm :)

Comment: Never mind, you're saving yourself an assignment operator call like this ;)